# show map Google Maps JavaScript API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, joomla

Hi everyone I try to use geolocalization for my webside made with joomla

I obtained the latitude and longitude and fine... But dont show me any map
In my code I am drawing the map inside a div

this is my code

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     function init() {
     if (navigator.geolocation) {
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
     var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);

    var mapOptions= {
     zoom: 14,
     center: myLatlng,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
     var marcador = new google.maps.Marker();
     marcador.setPosition(pos);
     marcador.setMap(map);

     }, function() {
     alert("su navegador no acepta geolocalización");
     });
     }
     }   
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
     </script>
```

in my head I have this

```
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js?ver=3.1.2'></script>
```

and his in my body

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

I have been read other post with the same problem, but I don't find the error in my code.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are some small errors in your code - hint: try using the Javascript console in Chrome to see these errors:

- You do not have 'pos' defined here: marcador.setPosition(pos);
- ...and you want to create a marker with it, so you have to use the LatLng object
- give your div a width and height (if you have not done it in your CSS file)

[Here is a JSFiddle with all there errors fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/BTN2c/)

Answer (score 1):

Where is `pos` defined?  This will most likely cause a JS error which will prevent the map displaying.

```
marcador.setPosition(pos);
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your div a size(width and height):

```
<div id="map" style="width:400px;height:300px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set width and height values for your #map and make sure the init() is called

here my jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3MTtc/1/